# An impassable/uncrossable country

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, word-meaning, idiomatic-language

Let's say there is a country which illegal immigrants are not able to enter. The country's borders have good security. Can we call that country

> **an impassable country**

or

> **an uncrossable country**

?

For example, do you think it would be fine to say any of these:

> **The US is impassable/uncrossable.**

> **The US has impassable/uncrossable borders.**

> **The US has is an impassable/uncrossable country.**

If we can't use "impassable" or "uncrossable" to mean that, which words would you recommend?

Comment: I would simply say that _«country x» has secure borders_ (or _... closed borders_ if it's not open to legal immigration or tourism).

Comment: _Entering_ a country and _crossing_ a country are not the same. If you can't enter it you might describe the country as _impenetrable_ rather than impassable or uncrossable.

Answer (score 1):

Both "crossable" and "passable" have the idea of "going through, from one side to the other":  "This road is so busy with cars it is uncrossable". You could use "uncrossable" to describe the borders, but not the country

You could perhaps use "unenterable": Not possible to be entered.

> The borders of the USA are uncrossable.

> The USA is now unenterable.

But that doesn't quite describe the situation that you describe, since with a visa, it is very easy to enter the country.

So for your precise context, I'd just use a paraphrase:

> The USA now has effective border security.

Comment: Thank you. Do you think it is wrong to call borders "impassable"?

Comment: Not completely wrong, but "crossing the border" is the idiom. But as you describe it, the borders are not "impassable" nor "uncrossable".  Those with visas cross them very easily.  An uncrossable border is one which it is impossible to cross.